# TFS 2012 CI doesn't run scheduled builds

Tags: build-automation

I've setup the build definition to trigger the build on scheduled basis. This build runs when ran manually but not when scheduled.

I've checked the date time etc on TFS server and also no build server. Could anyone help me understand:

1. How does TFS scheduled builds get picked up? SQL Agent or Service.
2. Where does it log the error if scheduled not run?
3. What are things that needs to be taken care to run the scheduled build?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the "Build even if nothing changes..." checkbox?

> How does TFS scheduled builds get picked up ? SQL Agent or Service.

The builds will be picked up by the build controller. Connect to your tfs account and head to the builds node in your webaccess UI. Here you should see your build definitions. You can see all the triggered builds here.

> Where does it log the error if scheduled not run?

Logs are associated with the builds above

> What are things that needs to be taken care to run the scheduled build?

This is like any other build definition just with a time trigger.